# How to groupby and average data greater than 0?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a huge dataframe containing sensor data every 5 minutes.
I added in a week number column.

I want to sum up the sunlight sensor column by week, but want to average the temperature column (`if temp > 0`).

```
ClimateDF.groupby('week').agg({'sunlight': 'sum', 'Temp': 'mean'})
```

This works, but how would I add in conditions? For example only average the temp `if temp > 0` etc?

Comment: show a dataframe we need to help you. Youu could use boolean indexing before groupby

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, this is what you need

```
ClimateDF.loc[ClimateDF['Temp']>0].groupby('week').agg({'sunlight': 'sum', 'Temp': 'mean'})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write a separate function and then use it in aggregation.

```
def my_func(x):
    return x[x>0].mean()

ClimateDF.groupby('week').agg({'sunlight': 'sum', 'Temp': my_func})
```

There are other ways as SH-SF already mentioned. Advantage of this is you can right complex function and as many functions as you want.